# Django : int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Plain'

Tags: python, django, model

I have rather simple problem i guess. But i cant find a solution. It's been a while since i was writing in python/django...

My simple problem is, when im trying to add new Plain by admin interface.

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Plain'
```

Site with form is rendering correctly, everything is fine till adding...

This is code of the models:

```
class Locomotion(models.Model):
    transportation_firm_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    transportation_number =  models.CharField(max_length=200)
    departure_date_time =  models.DateTimeField()
    arrival_date_time =  models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.transportation_name


class Plain(Locomotion):
    seat_number  = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    class_section =  models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Locomotion, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return "plain"


class Train(Locomotion):
    seat_number  = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    section_numbers =  models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Locomotion, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

And the same is happening when im trying to add Train or any other element of class extending Locomotion.

Comment: Full traceback please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `super`, you don't need to pass `self`:

```
super(Plain, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Also, note that usually, you want to call `super` passing the class that you are calling it from, `Plain` in this case.

Comment: It worked, i have no idea how, because i was doing the same thing earlier! Thanks!